# coin flipping kill program after 3 heads

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code with coin flipping. I want to print out every result of the coin flips until there 3 straight heads. I think my code should be correct but its just print 0 0 0 0. I think my while  loop is wrong.

---

```
import random

face = 0
total_heads = 0
total_tails = 0
count = 0
while face>=3:
    coin = random.randint(0, 1)
    if coin == 0:
        print("Heads\n")
        total_heads += 1
        count += 1
        face += 1
    elif coin == 1:
        print("Tails\n")
        total_tails += 1
        count += 1
        face == 0
print(total_tails)
print(total_heads)
print(count)
print(face)
```

---

Comment: You initialize `face` to 0 so your `while` is never met

Comment: your while condition is wrong `face<=3`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `while` loop to:

```
while face < 3:
```

otherwise it won't loop at all